# Have keycloak deny (granting) token when scope is empty

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, scopes

The Oauth rfc6749 specifies:
"If the client omits the scope parameter when requesting
authorization, the authorization server MUST either process the
request using a pre-defined default value or fail the request
indicating an invalid scope."

I need to implement the "fail the request" path, however, I can't (in keycloak) find a way to fail if there are no scopes in the claim. It just gives an access token with an empty scope (or the ones configured as default).